# How to restore consumable In App Purchases?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, icloud, keychain

I want to restore consumable In App Purchases for a game. This game has only consumable in app purchases such as:

- $0.99 for 1000 coins
- $1.99 for 3000 coins

Using `NSUserDefaults` to persist the coins is not good because the user could delete the app and when they reinstall, they lose their coins. Also Apple has a `restoreCompletedTransactions` method but this isn’t for consumables so the developer has to keep track of this.

Please don't mention to use `GameKit` (Game Center) or a Web Server. Are there any other solutions? I've read that `iCloud` and `Keychain` are two other possible solutions (not sure if these are good for this).

PS: There are many answers on SO that are a few years old and that won't work for my case, so I am asking here again.

Answer (score 1):

Keychain and iCloud is what you are looking at. Keychain data will also not be deleted when you uninstall the app.

There is a good helper on GitHub for keychain, which makes using it a breeze.

https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper

General read about data storing

[How secure is NSUserDefaults on iOS 8,9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35900523/how-secure-is-nsuserdefaults-on-ios-8-9/35900835#35900835)

To store your data in iCloud you should use key value storage for small data.

I use a singleton class to handle all this. For a simple example check out this answer I posted

[SpriteKit: Why does it wait one round for the score to update? (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684540/spritekit-why-does-it-wait-one-round-for-the-score-to-update-swift/33895778#33895778)

which is based in this great article

https://www.raywenderlich.com/63235/how-to-save-your-game-data-tutorial-part-1-of-2

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! What would you say is the optimal solution? I mentioned `iCloud` and `Keychain` but what is best, or is their other solutions that could be better. For example, one issue that comes to mind is, let's say the internet is not available and you use iCloud, does this make iCloud not good?

Comment: You should use both ideally. Local data first and than iCloud data as backup. This way your app will synchronize as well on all platforms. Check the last link

Comment: Ok I see so use `NSUserDefaults` combined with `iCloud`. Would you say this is better than `KeyChain` then? If yes, why so?

Comment: Nah I use keychain and iCloud. However sometimes trying to save to keychain fails, so I than use a user defaults until the next keychain save, than I delete it. This step is just to be extra sure, but not needed. You should never store sentivie data in NSUserdefaults.

Comment: So your essentially using 2 solutions just to be safe. This seems like more complicated for me... if you had to recommend one approach, which would it be?

Comment: Ok ignore the NSUserdefaults for now. If you want to be a good developer you will need at least 2, keychain and icloud. If you just want one than use keychain. You never use iCloud alone, it's as a backup. Also imagine your users are playing on an iPad and iPhone, ideally you want iCloud to sync this. Check the links I posted, especially the last one, it not very hard. If you don't want to use iCloud for now than use keychain.

Comment: Hey Eric, sorry I used the iOS app and though I was writing a comment not an answer.

Comment: Is `iCloud Keychain` what your referring to when you have to use both? I just found this online. Not sure if this is allowed to be used to store my custom data. Sorry for all the questions but never used any of these things before.

Comment: you want to save in iCloud  using iCloud key value storage for your data such as coins. If you are not reading the links I send you I cannot help. For local data use keychain, the wrapper on GitHub makes this literally the same as using NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Read this which is basically explains it the best. It's in obj c, so for a swift version of the code check the link in my answer. https://www.raywenderlich.com/63235/how-to-save-your-game-data-tutorial-part-1-of-2

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help! I am looking over everything now, I think this will work... I'll accept the answer once I read through everything.

Comment: No worries. Take your time and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113074/discussion-between-jel-and-crashoverride777).